# How can I test if a @output emit a value?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular-testing-library

I have a component that emit a value when call to a function,
how can I test if the @output emit a value ?
this is my function

```
@Output() emitDetail = new EventEmitter();

emitDetailFn() {
    this.emitDetail .emit(false);
}
```

and this is my test

```
  it('Detailfn should be called',()=>{

    let emitted: boolean;
    component.emitDetail .subscribe(value => {
      emitted = value
    })
    component.emitDetailFn();
    expect(emitted).toEqual(false)
})
```

but the coverage is red still in
[image]

Comment: You're almost there. Get rid of the `emitted` variable and move the `expect` statement into the `subscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test, you invoke the function `emitDetailFn`, the reported code coverage however relates to the function `emitDetailFnl`.

Nevertheless, your unit test could be written as follows:

```
it('should emit detail false',() => {
  spyOn(component.emitDetail, 'emit');
  component.emitDetailFn();
  expect(component.emitDetail.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
});
```

> For further details, please consult [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn) and [matchers](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html) from the Jasmine documentation.